# Why should you "never resort to polymorphism when initiality would do"?

Tags: type-theory, usage, soft-question

In the concluding statement of ["universe hierarchies"](https://pigworker.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/universe-hierarchies/), Conor McBride calls it

> [...] that key lesson which I learned from James McKinna: never resort to polymorphism when initiality will do.

How can you recognize when you could use [initiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) instead of polymorphism, and why should you prefer to use initiality?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Initiality comes with a powerful universal property which allows you to, internally, prove statements about the constructions you perform. If you give me an element of `data Nat = Z | S Nat`, I can perform induction on it.

Polymorphism on the other hand requires you to appeal to external principles such as parametricity (*) to recover similar reasoning principles. If you give me a function of type `(a -> a) -> a -> a`, I will know it is bound to be a natural number in disguise but will be powerless to exploit that fact.

Additionally in predicative systems with a tower of universes, initiality is typically size-respecting whereas an encoding via polymorphism will land you a definition that lives one level up in the hierarchy due to the universal quantification. If you want to iterate these constructions, that's bad news.

(*) caveat: there are type theories attempting to internalise parametricity

Comment: Wish I could up-vote multiple times. This answer is so incredibly obvious (post facto) I'm kind of ashamed that I didn't see it myself. I think the deep explanation (prefer size-respecting internal reasoning over external, potentially size-increasing reasoning) is one that can likely be instantiated multiple times to good effect.

Comment: In the third paragraph, do you mean "in *predicative* systems"?

Comment: @MikeShulman Good catch. Fixed it now. Thanks!